# Visual Stdio - C# Gridview CellClick action missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, eventhandler

I seem to be having an issue that i can't find a solution to.

I'm working on a project which includes a GridView with a column of 'Edit' buttons, however i can't seem to find the CellClick action, I've entered design view and clicked the lightening bolt only to see: [image]

This is from a fresh web application containing only a GridView i created to test this.

When trying to use the constructor i receive the following error:

dg1.CellClick += new System.EventHandler(dg1_CellClick);

'GridView' does not contain a definition for 'CellClick' and no extension method 'CellClick' accepting a first argument of type 'GridView' could be found.

Hopefully it's just me missing something but any advice would be extremely helpful,
Thanks :)

Comment: Where about's is the CellClick function placed? A partialview?

Comment: Could it be that you need the SelectedIndexChanged event? This seems like the expected result of a cell being clicked. This page shows the available events for this type of control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I've tried placing the constructor just about everywhere, including where various people on here have recommended but i have the same error every time

Comment: @Lennart I've just tried SelectedIndexChanged and that doesn't seem to fire at all when i click anywhere on a row.

Comment: If you place a button on each row you could handle it with the RowCommand event, if the corresponding button is a select button, you can handle it with the SelectedIndexChanged event. I've looked into it a bit more, and concluded that because this GridView is web based, it doesn't support native detection of cells being clicked. To accomplish what you're asking, I think it's not natively supported.

Comment: @Lennart Thanks for looking into this, i will find a way around it